# Is it possible to wipe/reformat the eMMC of a CM4 via ethernet?

Tags: networking, compute-module-4

I have CM4's that will not be directly accessible only remote access via ethernet. They'll be provisioned using CM Provision (aka PxE boot).

CM Provision doesn't seem to be able to re-provision a Pi device if it already has an OS installed, so how can one, in case of catastrophic failure, wipe/reformat the eMMC of a CM4 over network connection? Is it possible?